# Rally RestAPi-unable to update Test set results

Tags: java, rally

Though i am able to pull all the test cases present in a particular test set and modify or update all the test Results.
Test set is not reflecting the verdict(pass/fail) after updating the Test cases in that Test set.

If i navigate to one of the tescase detail page, i am able to see updated testcase result

This is the test-set status after updating the testcases
[image: test-set status after updating the testcases]

But when **one of those testcases** are opened i am able to see the **updated testcase result**

[image: updated testcase result]

code:
 QueryRequest testSetRequest = new QueryRequest("TestSet");
        testSetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] {"Name", "TestCases", "FormattedID"}));

```
    testSetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TS346"));

    QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(testSetRequest);

    if(testSetQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()){

    System.out.println("Successful: " + testSetQueryResponse.wasSuccessful());
    System.out.println("Size: " + testSetQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount());
    for (int i=0; i<testSetQueryResponse.getResults().size();i++){
        JsonObject testSetJsonObject = testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println("Name: " + testSetJsonObject.get("Name") + " ref: " + testSetJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString() + " Test Cases: " + testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonObject().get("_ref"));

 int numberOfTestCases = testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonObject().get("Count").getAsInt();
        System.out.println(numberOfTestCases);
        if(numberOfTestCases>0){
             QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest(testSetJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("TestCases"));
                testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID"));
                //load the collection
                JsonArray testCases = restApi.query(testCaseRequest).getResults();
                for (int j=0;j<numberOfTestCases;j++){
                    System.out.println(testCases.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID").getAsString());
                    String s= testCases.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID").getAsString();
                    testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
                    testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
                    testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", s));
                    QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
                    String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();

                    try{
                        //Add a Test Case Result
                        System.out.println("Creating Test Case Result...");
                        JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
                        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
                        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Date", "2013-11-29T18:00:00.000Z");
                        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Automated Selenium Test Runs");
                        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "208");
                        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", testCaseRef);

                        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
                        CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

                        if(createResponse.wasSuccessful()){
                            System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));
                            //Read Test Case
                            String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                            System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", ref));
                            GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
                            getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
                            GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
                            JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
                            System.out.println(String.format("Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s", obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString()));
                        } else {
                            String[] createErrors;
                            createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                            System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
                            for ( i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
                                System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally{

                    }
                }
        }
    }
    }
        else {
            String[] createErrors;
            createErrors = testSetQueryResponse.getErrors();
            System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
            for (int i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
            }
        }
```

so,Any idea of how to update the test set results

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some sample code that doesn't work? If so, what errors are being generated? Have you searched the forum for similar questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add the below code at the new test case result

newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestSet", testsetref);